# Excel find row of given string in range and copy to another tab

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of data that looks like this:

[image]

The above is in the 'NEW PLANNER WORKBOOK' tab. Tabs are shown below:

[image]

I'm trying to find a way to get the values for the rows where "Switched" occur (in this case 13 and 16 but won't always be the same and could be more or less than 2 instances) and take the information from columns B, F, and U associated to those rows and put them into the "Switched Info" tab.

For example in the above, row 13 has the following in columns B, F, and U:
[image]

So I would like to move values 'BBMK01150', '201T1ZFPMBHFLFEDC0PMBHFLFETMD', and 'WCA' to the 'Switched Info' tab which looks like this:

[image]

The end result looking something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this only using formulas?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If you want formulas, why the vba tags?

Comment: If VBA would work better I'm not opposed to it. This workbook will be used by many people so I was just trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Another method, hide all columns not wanted, filter on the desired description. Select the desired areas.  Find & replace ==> go to Special ==> visible cells only.  Copy and paste in the desired sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pivot table would be best.  But if a formula solution is wanted then:

These are all array formulas and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.
In A4 put:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('NEW PLANNER WORKBOOK'!$B:$B,MATCH(SMALL(IF('NEW PLANNER WORKBOOK'!$A:$A="Switched",'NEW PLANNER WORKBOOK'!$B:$B),COUNTA($A$3:$A3)),'NEW PLANNER WORKBOOK'!$B:$B,0)),"")
```

In B4:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('NEW PLANNER WORKBOOK'!$F:$F,MATCH(SMALL(IF('NEW PLANNER WORKBOOK'!$A:$A="Switched",'NEW PLANNER WORKBOOK'!$B:$B),COUNTA($A$3:$A3)),'NEW PLANNER WORKBOOK'!$B:$B,0)),"")
```

In C4:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('NEW PLANNER WORKBOOK'!$U:$U,MATCH(SMALL(IF('NEW PLANNER WORKBOOK'!$A:$A="Switched",'NEW PLANNER WORKBOOK'!$B:$B),COUNTA($A$3:$A3)),'NEW PLANNER WORKBOOK'!$B:$B,0)),"")
```

Again Each needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Then they can be copied down for as many rows as desired.

One Note.  This will be slow.  To speed up, Change all the full column references to the specific area, ie $A:$A to $A$6:$A$1000, if 1000 was the last row of data.

Comment: @mtcrts70 I just realized a mistake in the formulas that would cause missing one of the lines.  Please use the new formulas.  I basically got rid of the `+ 1` after the `COUNTA($A$3:$A3)` on all three formulas.  I forgot that it will count the header in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this with code, but I think you could just use pivot tables if you didn't want to use a macro. Use the table in the New Planner Workbook worksheet as your data source and then make a pivot table on a new sheet and filter the data.